# Finding out which vectors are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We have following vectors: $(1,2,1,3),(2,-1,3,-1),(3,1,4,2),(1,-3,1,-2)$. I'm trying to find out which of those are linearly dependent and remove them. What I did was to create a matrix: $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1\\ 
2 & -1 & 1 & -3\\ 
1 & 3 & 4 & 1\\ 
3 & -1 & 2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$ and by solving the matrix I found out, that the last row will get removed, so they are linearly dependend. However, how do I find out which two vectors are linearly dependent? Thanks

Comment: @postmortes I found out by transforming it into a jordanian matrix. But I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @postmortes $R_1+R_2 = R_4$?  Check again.

Comment: Try reducing the matrix to row echelon form.  When you get a row of zeros, you will have established dependence, and the sequence of operations will tell what is is.

Comment: @saulspatz not sure I see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches you can use here.

One approach is to check the linear independence of set of vectors iteratively.  Keep only those vectors which increase the dimension of the space spanned by our collected vectors so far and discard any redundant vectors which did not increase the dimension of the span.

The set containing only the first vector is obviously linearly independent (*the only way a set containing only one vector would be dependent is if it were the zero vector*).  The set containing the first two is also obviously linearly independent (*as neither is the zero vector and they are clearly not multiples of one another*).

Now, the question becomes if the set of the first three are linearly independent and if the set of all four are linearly independent.  You will find that the set with the first three are not independent, so the third vector is redundant and should not be included, but the set with the first, second, and fourth are dependent.  As such, you can safely say that the first, second, and fourth are **a** maximally independent subset of your set of vectors (*not necessarily the only one*).

---

Another option is to create a matrix by using each of your vectors as the *columns* just as you did in your attempt above (*not the rows in this case which would have been useful for other tasks*).  Now, by row reducing this matrix, the locations of the pivots will reveal to you which columns can form a maximally linearly independent set.

You will find that after row reducing this matrix, the pivots are located in the first, second, and fourth columns so this implies that it is the first, second, and fourth vectors that you can use to form a maximally independent subset of your set of vectors.

---

(*Note: there are potentially many different maximally independent subsets of vectors, say for example the first, third, and fourth instead.  The two processes above will prioritize having the sum of the subindicies of your vectors be minimized.  You could find different maximally independent subsets by changing the order in which you use your original vectors*)

Comment: So which vectors are linearly dependent? According to my notes, it's 2. and 3.

Comment: @Frederica Naming the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ respectively, the *set* of vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly dependent.  This is despite each pair of vectors being linearly independent.  A choice of a maximally independent subset of your vectors could be $v_1,v_2,v_4$, or equivalently it could have been $v_1,v_3,v_4$ or even $v_2,v_3,v_4$.

Comment: @Frederica there is no "one" vector that is "linearly dependent" on its own (*except for the zero vector*).  Linear dependence is always in reference to interactions between vectors.  You could have asked, which vector is "redundant" (*and as such could have been removed while still keeping the span and dimension of the span the same*) to which the answer is any single one of $v_1,v_2,v_3$, but only if you remove only one of them and not multiple.

Answer (score 2):

Just reduce it to row echelon form, keeping track of what you do.  Start with $$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1 &R_1\\ 
2 & -1 & 1 & -3 &R_2\\ 
1 & 3 & 4 & 1 &R_3\\ 
3 & -1 & 2 & -2 &R_4
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1 &R_1\\ 
0 & -5 & -5 & -5 &R_2-2R_1\\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &R_3 -R_1\\ 
0 & -7 & -7 & -5 &R_4-3R_1
\end{pmatrix}

and continue in this fashion.

Comment: But there are rows and my vectors are in columns.

Comment: @Frederica There are reasons why you might want to use then as rows instead when constructing a matrix, just as there are reasons why you might want to use them as columns when constructing a matrix.  I recommend looking into what the uses for each are as they do vary but are both useful.

Comment: @Frederica Sorry, I didn't really that.  Just use column echelon form instead; or write the vectors is rows.

Answer (score 0):

In the matrix, just check the rank (of the $3 \times 3$ minors).
The minor(s) with highest rank (might be $3$, $2$ or $1$), contain the "base", the other  vectors will be dependent on that base.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter how you construct the matrix (row-wise or column-wise) as long as you keep track of the vectors (row or column).

Column-wise. By definition, the given vectors $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\vec{v}_3,\vec{v}_4$ are linearly independent if there exist scalars $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ not all zero, such that: 
$$a_1\vec{v}_1+a_2\vec{v}_2+a_3\vec{v}_3+a_4\vec{v}_4=\vec{0} \Rightarrow\\
a_1\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
2 \\ 
1 \\ 
3 \end{pmatrix}+a_2
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\ 
-1 \\ 
3 \\ 
-1 \end{pmatrix}+a_3
\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\ 
1 \\ 
4 \\ 
2 \end{pmatrix}+a_4
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
-3 \\ 
1 \\ 
-2 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow \\
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1\\ 
2 & -1 & 1 & -3\\ 
1 & 3 & 4 & 1\\ 
3 & -1 & 2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\ 
a_2 \\ 
a_3 \\ 
a_4 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow $$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1\\ 
2 & -1 & 1 & -3\\ 
1 & 3 & 4 & 1\\ 
3 & -1 & 2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1\\ 
0 & -5 & -5 & -5\\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & -7 & -7 & -5
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$
which implies 
$$a_4=0, \\
a_2+a_3+a_4=0 \Rightarrow a_2=-a_3, \\
a_1+2a_2+3a_3+a_4=0 \Rightarrow a_1-2a_3+3a_3=0 \Rightarrow a_1=-a_3 \Rightarrow \\
a_1\vec{v}_1+a_2\vec{v}_2+a_3\vec{v}_3+a_4\vec{v}_4=\vec{0} \Rightarrow \\
-a_3\vec{v}_1-a_3\vec{v}_2+a_3\vec{v}_3=\vec{0} \Rightarrow \\
\vec{v}_1+\vec{v}_2=\vec{v}_3$$
Hence, the vectors $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\vec{v}_3$ are interdependent. Removing any one of them will do.

Row-wise. Do RREF:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 3\\ 
2 & -1 & 3 & -1\\ 
3 & 1 & 4 & 2\\ 
1 & -3 & 1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 3\\ 
\color{red}0 & \color{red}{-5} & \color{red}1 & \color{red}{-7}\\ 
\color{red}0 & \color{red}{-5} & \color{red}1 & \color{red}{-7}\\ 
0 & -5 & 0 & -5
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 3\\ 
0 & -5 & 1 & -7\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & -1 & 2
\end{pmatrix},$$
which again implies the vectors $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\vec{v}_3$ are interdependent. Removing any one of them will do.